# Android application - Statistics VolleyBall game : UML chart

Tags: android, uml, use-case

I have a specific question that I can't resolve. This question is an UML problem, there is my application :

I would like to create a Statistics Volleyball application.
I want to change the parameter of a player in real time by modifying a table in attributes player.
The final goal is to get information about players from teams and for different matches. The problem for me is my UML representation. I don't think it's the best way to represent a sport team but I can't find it. Could you help me to clarify the UML representation following.

[UML model (Players,Teams,Matches,Sets)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIE7K.png)

For me, the links in the UML model are "is composed of" and the dotted line "is associated to".

At the end, I want to guide the user with this following tree of decisions to display the statistics:

Choose a Team => Choose the matches from the team or display global stats of the team => Display all the stats from 1 match or choose a set in the match => Display all the stats from the set.

Can you tell me if this UML chart is right and which classes should I extend from (Ex: Players & Team) to get all the information that I need when I want to change the statistics of a Player during a Match and then display all those stats after.

Thanks for you help.

Best regards.

Julien Weber

Comment: It does not seem like you have a programming problem here - you are asking for a review of your UML chart - for your application you should already have some ideas about some of the questions you have raised here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- All your aggregations are drawn the wrong way.
- The Dependency (dotted line) is superfluous.
- Name of opponent in Match is bad design. Create two associations with `Player` and name them `player1` and `player2` or the like.
- There is too few information about the statics you want. But you should create an association class `Statistics` between `Player` and `Match`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to get the statistics of one Team so I choosed to put the name of the Opponent as a keywork for different Match.